# How to delete/remove Views display programmatically?

Tags: views, 6

Any idea how can I remove or delete Views display programmatically?

I have a Views that has 5 displays and I want to delete one of them. For the sake of avoiding manual intervention I want to do it automatically via code. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I had a similar question and found an answer at Sivaji's Drupal Site - http://sivaji.drupalgardens.com/how-disable-views-programmatically-when-offering-module-disabled Plugging my view name in to lines 5 and 6 worked for me in a hook_update_n().

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example you would put in mymodule.install

```
/**
* Disable workbench views
*/
function mymodule_update_7001() {
    // an array of views (their view name) I want to disable
    $viewnames = array(
      'workbench_current_user',
      'workbench_edited',
      'workbench_moderation',
      'workbench_recent_content',
    );

    // grab the array of views that are already disabled
    $views_status = variable_get('views_defaults', array());

    // add our views to be disabled to the list
    foreach ($viewnames as $key => $viewname) {
      $views_status[$viewname] = TRUE;
    }

    // reset the variable with the new list
    variable_set('views_defaults', $views_status);

    // empty cache now
    if (function_exists('views_invalidate_cache')) {
      views_invalidate_cache();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer. question is about removing of views display